# Crystal Report generates on dev box, but not web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a CrystalReportViewer control on an ASPX page. On my development machine the Crystal Report generates properly. However, when I publish it and run it on a web server I get the following pop-up screen. Entering in the password does nothing. The same screen just pops up again:

[image]

The datasource is configured in the .rpt file. So my code on the CrystalReportViewer is simply the following:

```
if (Request.QueryString["report"].ToString() != "")
{
    ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
    doc.Load(Request.QueryString["report"].ToString());
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
}
```

If it helps, some of the (more important looking) datasource properties in the .rpt file are as follows:

- Database Type: ODBC (RDO)
- DSN: plmprod
- Server Type: ODBC - plmprod
- Use DSN Default Properties: True

Also, I have the same ODBC/System DSN (named plmprod) setup on my development machine and on the web server. Using the "Test Connection" option they both test successfully.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Nor do I know much about Crystal Reports.

What could be the problem that is causing the report to not generate on the web server?

Comment: If enter in the password again, does the report render? I know with Crystal Reports Enterprise, I have to save the password to the data source within CMC (Central Management Console). Otherwise, I have to enter the password in multiple times if I have sub-reports, dynamic cascading prompts, etc.

Comment: @Sun - Thank you for my only response to this question in 24 hrs. I got it working right about the time you posted your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a 64 bit ODBC/DSN on the web server and it now works!

All of my Crystal Reports Windows apps work fine around the company with 32 bit DSNs so I made a false assumption that is what the web server would want as well...not so as I found out.